# SelfOrganising Search using arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I need to implement  `search()` method which takes an integer as input to search, each time an integer is found, move it to the first position in the array(and move everything else back one space to make room).

For Example:

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6}
```

my input is: `5`

Then the resultant array should be : `{5,1,2,3,4,6}`

Please help me in solving this problem,
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Help you how?  Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: What problems did you run into in your implementation attempts?

Comment: @Malt - Iam able to place the integer at the first position, but couldn't move the next array elements

Comment: @Malt - Can I share my code?

Comment: int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };                                                                                                                  
   public void search(int numberToBeFound) {
  int count = a.length;
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   if (a[i] == numberToBeFound) {
    temp=a[0];
    a[0] = a[i];
   }
                }
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6},temp=0;
        int x=5;//test number
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
            if (a[i]==x) {  
                temp=a[i];
                for(int j=i;j>0;j--)
                    a[j]=a[j-1];
                break;
            }
        }
        a[0]=temp;

        //Let's test the logic
        for(int n:a)
            System.out.print(n+"\t");
    }
}
```